# Laravel permission issue in server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

> I have given 'storage/framework/session' folder to 755 recursively
>    but session created inside it has 644 in server,can anyone tell me
>   why it is?

Comment: you have to give such permission to all subfolders of storage

Comment: yes it is given recursively, im using ubuntu in server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When giving permissions to folders that have subfolders, and you want those affected as well, you should add the -R (recursive) command, example:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
```

Don't forget to give the same permissions to bootstrap/cache folder. However most folders should be 755 and 644 for the files inside. If you're having issues, then check which group/user owns the folder/files . See if it gets solved by changing the group owners to www-data, like this:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: how can i change group on live environment? it is already 755

Comment: You either use sudo chgrp for only group or chown for both name and group (remember adding -R command will do it recursively to all the subfolders): sudo chown username:groupname directoryname